# 'contentEditable' div inside react-native webview is hiding behind Keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, webview, contenteditable

I have used a contentEditable div inside a webview for some editor functionality in one of my app. The html code seams to work fine and responding to keyboard show and hide action in my android chrome browser but when i tried the same html code with the webview in react-native it won't responds to the keyboard and content hide behind the keyboard.

I have tried scrolling it to the end of the div and auto increase it's height according to content but nothing works.

import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { View, WebView } from 'react-native';

class webviewEditor extends Component{

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <WebView
                source={{
                    html: `
                        < head >
                            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;" />
                            <style type="text/css">
                            html, body {height: 100%;}
                            body {
                                margin: 0;
                                }
                            #wrap {
                                height: 100%;
                                width: 100%;
                                overflow-y: scroll;
                                -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
                            }
                            #editor {
                                padding: 10px;
                            }
                        </style>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                    <div id="wrap">
                        <div id="editor" contenteditable="true">

                        </div>
                    </div></body>
            `}}
                ref={web => { this.webview = web }}
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                scalesPageToFit={false}
                scrollEnabled={false}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

I expect the result to be the webview will scroll to the above of the keyboard just like in the browser but it won't in the app inside webview.

Comment: Have you tried using a ```KeyboardAvoidingView``` as your container view? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview

Comment: I have but keyboardavoidingview won't work with the contents of webview.